# How to setup inline editing

Tags: 8, entities

I'm using a stock version of Drupal 8.1 and trying to figure out how to setup the quick edit inline module. I just want to be able to edit the fields on the fly without having to go to the edit page. I looked all over and I can't seem to find any setting to turn on the quick edit module for a specific field. What else could I be missing? The module is indeed turned on.

Comment: Standard installation? I just install with standard profile and the quickedit is ready without changing settings.

Comment: yeah its standard on 8.1.x. can you show me a screenshot of what I should be seeing? I'm using core bartik aswell.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to allow quick edit on a certain fields. There is no settings for that AFAIK.

Comment: @duckx hover over the body and click on "quick edit", [see pic](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Ce5E1.jpg) After quick edit is enabled, you can hover over the title, user name, date, etc... to change them

Comment: Also, what does "stock version" means? 
+1: it is enabled by default. It should work.